# Получение записей из сообщества ВК

Tags: html, python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как можно получить 5 последних записей из сообщества, например, тжурнал? Пробовал через Vk api, но он все время ругается на токен. У меня не получается получить токен своей страницы. Как это можно реализовать на питоне? Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Процесс получения access_token описан тут:  [клик](http://all-for-vkontakte.ru/catalog/access-token-vkontakte)

Пример реализации:

```
import vk
apikey = 'ключ'
session = vk.Session(access_token = apikey)
api = vk.API(session,timeout=60)
#domain - короткий адрес сообщества или пользователя, для ID сообщества или пользователей - owner_id
wall_content = api.wall.get(domain='team', count=5)
print(wall_content)
```

Пример полученной (1) записи

`[316, {'id': 337270, 'from_id': -22822305, 'to_id': -22822305, 'date': 1514744166, 'marked_as_ads': 0, 'post_type': 'post', 'text': 'Целый год мы радовались и грустили, мечтали и влюблялись, были в контакте с близкими и делились впечатлениями с новыми людьми. <br><br>Настройтесь на праздничный лад без суеты: включите подборку [club147845620|новогодней музыки] под запах спелых мандаринов, запишите [club139533130|весёлую историю с одной из масок], устройте торжественную [club135678176|прямую трансляцию], поделитесь [club76477496|итогами года] и расскажите, как пройдут Ваши #каникулыстолком. <br><br>Мы подготовили подборку [club49849615|бесплатных подарков], чтобы Вы могли разделить праздник с теми, кто дорог — независимо от их местоположения.<br><br>Пускай год Собаки подарит каждому честность, справедливость и верность. Искренние эмоции и непреклонную веру в чудо. <br><br>С Новым годом!<br>До встречи в 2018 ', 'media': {'type': 'photo', 'owner_id': -22822305, 'item_id': 456254006, 'thumb_src': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c834303/v834303728/6f6fd/2L69tvVeR3U.jpg'}, 'attachment': {'type': 'photo', 'photo': {'pid': 456254006, 'aid': -7, 'owner_id': -22822305, 'user_id': 100, 'src': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c834303/v834303728/6f6fd/2L69tvVeR3U.jpg', 'src_big': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c834303/v834303728/6f6fe/ec-hUh9pfkI.jpg', 'src_small': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c834303/v834303728/6f6fc/X-hOxA9oHhg.jpg', 'src_xbig': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c834303/v834303728/6f6ff/IaKHETS4ajA.jpg', 'src_xxbig': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c834303/v834303728/6f700/wkrHNdAy-DE.jpg', 'src_xxxbig': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c834303/v834303728/6f701/EJV_9xJ5eKs.jpg', 'width': 2500, 'height': 1564, 'text': '', 'created': 1514727808, 'access_key': '5f3ed63914003dce4b'}}, 'attachments': [{'type': 'photo', 'photo': {'pid': 456254006, 'aid': -7, 'owner_id': -22822305, 'user_id': 100, 'src': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c834303/v834303728/6f6fd/2L69tvVeR3U.jpg', 'src_big': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c834303/v834303728/6f6fe/ec-hUh9pfkI.jpg', 'src_small': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c834303/v834303728/6f6fc/X-hOxA9oHhg.jpg', 'src_xbig': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c834303/v834303728/6f6ff/IaKHETS4ajA.jpg', 'src_xxbig': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c834303/v834303728/6f700/wkrHNdAy-DE.jpg', 'src_xxxbig': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c834303/v834303728/6f701/EJV_9xJ5eKs.jpg', 'width': 2500, 'height': 1564, 'text': '', 'created': 1514727808, 'access_key': '5f3ed63914003dce4b'}}], 'post_source': {'type': 'vk'}, 'comments': {'count': 324, 'can_post': 1}, 'likes': {'count': 1687, 'user_likes': 0, 'can_like': 1, 'can_publish': 1}, 'reposts': {'count': 59, 'user_reposted': 0}, 'online': 1, 'reply_count': 324}]`